# Why deleting .idea folder and restart Android Studio makes app faild to save image

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a very basic feature into my own app: save the displayed image to file, and notice galerry to update.

I found this github project, https://github.com/zhouxu88/SaveImgToGallery , but it is with old gradle configs, thus I've update related configs, then Android Studio generated app run OK on my phone.

However, when I turn of AS, deleting .idea folder (since AS give a warning `Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules`), restart AS, the re-generated APP can't get privilege to save image.

Android Studio version 193, gradle version 6.1.1.

Why re-generate .idea folder makes the app failed to get granted priviledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because SaveImgToGallery (that is very old) is based on an extra-old library: easypermissions ([GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)) 0.3.0, I think it is very bugged, but there are newer release (3 and 2). Try not to link the library but to import because they are very little modules.

Comment: After several hours struggling and debugging, I notice the root cause was two: 1) I didn't uninstall my previous app, this affect how permission behaves; 2) I didn't know and didn't notice targetSdkVersion, 29 is important than before. Of course, I should use new version of easypermission, its old version may not handle API 29 stuffs.